# Compilestatic annotation on an interceptor with data response

Tags: grails, interceptor, compile-static

In an interceptor I have this code:

```
render(contentType: 'text/json') {
  msg 'Message to show'
}
```

It is not possible to add the `@CompileStatic` annotation on this interceptor, as the `msg` variable isn't declared.
Is there any way to write this in a *"compilestatic"* friendly way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the json builder directly

```
def json = new JsonBuilder()
json.call([msg: 'Message to show'])

render(text: json.toString(), contentType: 'text/json')
```

Comment: Just what i needed. Thanks James